# Proof of minor claim related to the Twin Primes Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, twin-primes, oeis

**Question:**

How can it be proven that integers of the form $n=6jk\pm j \pm k;\ j,k\in \mathbb N^*,$ are the only ones which (when multiplied by $6$) correspond to multiples of $6$ *not* between twin primes? How do we know that no other integers exist such that when they are multiplied by $6$ their products are also not between twin primes?

**Context:**

A few years ago, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550916/find-all-integers-n-such-that-n-neq-6xy-pm-x-pm-y) question hoping that someone might have some advice about tackling Diophantine equations of this sort. No such luck.

Specifically, the question has to do with finding integer solutions $n, j, k \in \mathbb N^*$ to the following equation 
$$
n=6jk\pm j\pm k
$$

Since every pair of twin primes must have a multiple of $6$ between them, it is a simple matter to show that integers, $n$, of this form correspond to multiples of $6$ that **don't** flag a twin prime pair - i.e. $6n+1$ or $6n-1$ is not prime.

The reasoning is simply that whenever a multiple of $6$ is divisible by an integer one less or one greater than some other multiple of $6$, then there is a nearby multiple of $6$ which is adjacent to a multiple of that same number one less or one greater. For instance, $30$ is divisible by $5$, so neither $24$ nor $36$ can fall between twin primes since they are adjacent to $25$ and $35$ respectively. Likewise, $210$ is a multiple of $6$ which is not between twin primes since $209=11\times 19$, and this can be determined with the formula since $210=6\times 35$, $35=33+2$, and $33$ is a multiple of $11=6\times 2 -1$.

In other words, this equation acts as a sieve selecting out multiples of $6$ which definitely do not neighbor twin primes. Therefore, this line of reasoning imposes a necessary condition on any potential twin prime candidates.

Is this condition not only necessary but sufficient?

OEIS contributor Jon Perry seems to think that it is sufficient since he claims [here](https://oeis.org/A002822) that "6n-1 and 6n+1 are twin primes iff n is not of the form 6ab +- a +- b."

The proof of the conditional is fairly straightforward (as I have already explained), but the converse is far less obvious to me.

How can one prove that "If $n$ is not of the form $6ab\pm a \pm b$, then $6n-1$ and $6n+1$ are twin primes"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have $n$ that cannot be expressed in the form $6ab \pm a \pm b$ (for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$).

Now suppose $6n-1$ is not prime, so $6n-1=(6a'+1)(6b'-1)$ (for some $a',b' \in \mathbb{N}$) contradicting the hypothesis.

OR suppose $6n+1$ is not prime, so  $6n+1=(6a'+1)(6b'+1)$ (for some $a',b' \in \mathbb{N}$) or $6n+1=(6a'-1)(6b'-1)$ (for some $a',b' \in \mathbb{N}$)  either way, contradicting the hypothesis.

If a number $n$ that cannot be expressed in the form $6ab \pm a \pm b$ then $6n \pm 1$ will be a prime pair & prime pairs can only be generated by $n$ with this property (apart from the pair $(3,5)$).

Comment: $6n-1=(6a+1)(6b-1)\iff n=6ab-a+b$ and not all $n$ can be written this way.

Comment: For the most part I understand the argument, but I don't see why (for instance) $6n-1=(6a'+1)(6b'-1)$. Why can you make this very specific claim about the factors of $6n-1$? As far as I can tell, the only thing we can say for sure about $6n-1$ is that it can be decomposed into the product of two integers at least one of which is a prime (and therefore able to be written as $6a'\pm 1$). How do we know that it can definitely be written as the product of two numbers that differ from a multiple of 6 by 1 in the way you have written?

Comment: If $m=6n-1$ then $m \equiv 5 \mod 6$. The only way to pair of numbers (modulo 6) that will multiply to give $5$ are $1$ & $5$. So if $M=AB$ then $A \equiv 1 \mod 6$ and $B \equiv 5 \mod 6$ (or the other way around)

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the answer!